# How to fix a transpose function that fails to properly do a 3x2 and 4x3 matrix?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, transpose

I'm having trouble where my transpose function is great at transposing a square matrix; but, it does an awful job when it's a rectangle. It just doesn't make a new column for certain elements after transposing, and I'm unsure how to fix this issue. I've tried altering the loop to no avail. I was thinking about altering the display function, but I felt like it would cause some issues.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix();

    void transpose(int &numRows, int &numCols);

    void fill2dArray(int &numRows, int &numCols);

    void display2dArray(int &numRows, int &numCols) const;

private:
    static const int ROW_MAX = 10, COL_MAX = 10;
    double data[ROW_MAX][COL_MAX];
};

Matrix::Matrix()
{
    data[10][10] = {};
}

void Matrix::transpose(int &numRows, int &numCols)
{
    for (int r=0; r<numRows; ++r)
    {
        for (int c=0; c<numCols; ++c)
        {
            if (r < c)
            {
                std::swap(data[r][c],data[c][r]);
            }
        }
    }
}

void Matrix::display2dArray(int &numRows, int &numCols) const
{
    for (int r=0; r<numRows; ++r)
    {
        for (int c=0; c<numCols; ++c)
        {
            std::cout << "   " << data[r][c] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void Matrix::fill2dArray(int &numRows, int &numCols)
{
    for (int r=0; r<numRows; ++r)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter " << numCols << " values for row #" << r << std::endl;
        for (int c = 0; c < numCols; ++c)
        {
            std::cin >> data[r][c];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "You may enter up to 10 rows and 10 columns of numbers." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "\n   How many rows? ";
    int numRows;
    std::cin >> numRows;

    std::cout << "How many columns? ";
    int numCols;
    std::cin >> numCols;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    Matrix matrix;
    matrix.fill2dArray(numRows,numCols);

    std::cout << "Contents of the " << numRows << " x " << numCols << " array:" << std::endl;
    matrix.display2dArray(numRows,numCols);

    std::cout << "\nAfter transpose" << std::endl;
    matrix.transpose(numRows, numCols);
    matrix.display2dArray(numRows, numCols);
}
```

Comment: `data[10][10] = {};` exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds. Valid indexes into `data` are 0 through 9.

Comment: You only swap elements if `r < c`, which means that in a 3x2 matrix you never touch elements in the third row.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik i didn't know about the undefined behavior; how would one go about fixing it? i'm roughly thinking about doing `data[][] = {}` or `data = {}`; for the second portion; i realized the condition was doing that after noticing that some parts of the swap were being skipped cause of the condition during debug; i'm just not sure what other condition i should replace it with--i tried doing no condition at all but that causes garbage to be displayed in the output

Comment: What do you hope to achieve with `data[10][10] = {}` or `data[][] = {}` or `data = {}`? Just drop that line.

Comment: The simplest approach is probably to transpose a square matrix of size `MxM` where `M=max(numRows, numCols)`. Any smaller sub-matrix will also happen to get transposed as a side effect.

Comment: I'm trying to initialize all elements with 0 for that line.

Comment: `Matrix::Matrix() : data{} {}`

Comment: My professor doesn't like inlining because it goes against some OOP principles he follows closely, but how is that any different from the 3 pieces of code I mentioned? Moreover, after the max is found do I just continue with the same logic of my transpose function?

Comment: This code compiles and works. Those three pieces either don't compile, or exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: I gave you an idea. Implementing it is left as an exercise for the reader. It's your homework after all.